# Laravel forgen key not passing tests

Tags: laravel, tdd, laravel-5.8

I am working through TDD in Laravel. I have a `Location` factory that looks like this:

**LocationFactory**

```php
$factory->define(Location::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'owner_id' => function () {
        return factory(User::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'name' => $faker->company,
    ...
    ];
});
```

My test looks like this:

**LocationTest**

```
// Allow Laravel to handle the exception.
$this->withExceptionHandling();

// Create an authenticated user instance.
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

// Create the location instances via a factory.
$location = factory(Location::class)->create();

// An authenticated user can send a POST request to /locations to create a new location.
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/locations', $location->toArray());

// Assert the system should persist the data to the database.
$this->assertDatabaseHas('locations', [
    'id' => $location->id,
    'owner_id' => $location->owner_id,
    'name' => $location->name,
    'description' => $location->description,
    'address' => $location->address,
    'address2' => $location->address2,
    'city' => $location->city,
    'state' => $location->state,
    'zip' => $location->zip,
    'created_at' => $location->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $location->updated_at,
    'deleted_at' => null,
]);

// Assert the response.
$response->assertSessionHasNoErrors();
$response->assertStatus(200);
```

The error I am getting is pretty obvious:

```
[
    "The owner id field is required."
]
Failed asserting that true is false.
```

However, I know I'm getting an `owner_id` in my tests:

```
dd($location);

 #original: array:12 [
     "owner_id" => 665
     ...
```

Here is a snippet of my controller - how I'm saving the location.

**LocationController**

```
$attributes = $request->validate([
    'owner_id' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required',
    ...
]);

$location = Location::create($attributes);
$location->owner_id = auth()->id();
$location->save();
```

My Location model looks like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'description', 'address', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip',
];

/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [
    'owner_id',
];
```

Using [telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/telescope) I can see that `owner_id` is not in the array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Edit**

Checking my migration to make sure the field is there:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('owner_id');
```

While looking right at the raw database, I can see the column exists and has data.

Comment: Is `owner_id` in your `hidden` attributes? If so, the value will not be included in your array when you call `toArray()`.

Comment: It is, but I have tried removing it and still no luck. Just using Tinker to generate a Location (via the factory) does not return an `owner_id`

Comment: I have tried to just hard code a number in my factory: `owner_id => 1` but that does not seem to get picked up either. Is it how I am saving the Location in my controller?

Comment: Did you restart your tinker after you removed it from the `hidden` attribute?

Comment: I did not, thank you for calling that out. Now it is showing: `owner_id: 50, name: "Ullrich, Kunde and Koss",`

That seems to be passing now, but I see `Expected status code 200 but received 500.` It must be the way I'm trying to save since I have `owner_id` as guarded.

Comment: Yes since it's guarded, you cannot mass assign it the way you are doing it.